# Generate wsdl documentation

Tags: c#, wsdl

I have some WSDL and I would like to generate a web page with the documentation with parameters, method name, method decription, etc...:

Do you have some c# code to do this please ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx

Thats how ASPX hosted services do it.

Hope this helps,